# Add a field with COUNT from a related table

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to figure out how to add a field with a count from another table.

I have a table with 'items' and another with 'tasks'. The tasks have a foreignkey to the items.

**models.py**

```
class Item(MPTTModel):
    item_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    item_parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

class Task(models.Model):
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=550)
    item = models.ForeignKey('item.Item')
```

And the view where i make the query and want to add a column with a count to each row of items.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    all_root_items = Item.objects.filter(item_parent__isnull=True)    

    context = {
        'nodes': all_root_items ,       
    }
    return render(request, 'tasks/index.html', context)
```

So I want for each item in all_root_items to have a field (ex. 'task_count'). Which is the number of tasks assign to that item.

I've tried so many different ideas. But none works.

Edit to clarify my question.

all_root_item would look like this

```
items [
   {"item_title" : "item 1", "item_parent" : ""},
   {"item_title" : "item 2", "item_parent" : ""}
]
```

And I want to add task count for each item. So it will look like this

```
items [
{"item_title" : "item 1", "item_parent" : "", "task_count" : "6"},
{"item_title" : "item 2", "item_parent" : "", "task_count" : "2"}
]
```

Comment: You would like to show that in the Admin or the template?

Comment: @hansTheFranz in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. This is what i changed

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    all_root_items = Item.objects.filter(item_parent__isnull=True)    

    for item in all_root_items:
        cntTasks = Task.objects.filter(item=item).count()
        item.task_count = cntTasks
    context = {
        'nodes': all_root_items ,       
    }
    return render(request, 'tasks/index.html', context)
```

And in the template I can call the count I added with:

```
for a in nodes
   a.snag_count
endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all tasks for each item in your all_root_items, you can do following,

```
item_list = []
for item in all_root_items:
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(item=item)
    for task in tasks:
        item_list.append({'item_title': task.item.item_title, 'item_parent': task.item.item_parent})
print item_list
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain good enough. I have updated my question to clarify how I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Write your action in **views.py** as follows:

```
def index(request):
   all_root_items = Item.objects.filter(item_parent__isnull=True)
   item_list = []
   for item in all_root_items:
      tasks = Task.objects.filter(item=item)

      item_list.append({'item_title': item.item_title, 'item_parent': item.item_parent, "task_count" : len(tasks)  })

   context = {
     'nodes': item_list,       
   }
   return render(request, 'tasks/index.html', context)
```

You are counting tasks including each item and adding  it to the object array.